# Access Query getting error 3141 while applying report filter from Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to implement report criteria from Form but getting the error 3141. I don't know whats wrong. Can anybody help please?

The form has following fields: Invoice number, Start date, End data, Customer Name and Vendor name.

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Const strBaseSql As String = "SELECT INVOICE.INV_NUMBER, INVOICE.INV_DATE, CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_LNAME, CUSTOMER.CUS_FNAME, CUSTOMER.CUS_AREACODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_PHONE, LINE.LINE_NUMBER, LINE.P_CODE, PRODUCT.P_DESCRIPT, LINE.LINE_UNITS, LINE.LINE_PRICE, [LINE_PRICE]*[LINE_UNITS] AS LineSubtotal" & _
                         "FROM VENDOR INNER JOIN (CUSTOMER INNER JOIN (PRODUCT INNER JOIN (INVOICE INNER JOIN LINE ON INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = LINE.INV_NUMBER) ON PRODUCT.P_CODE = LINE.P_CODE) ON CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE = INVOICE.CUS_CODE) ON VENDOR.V_CODE = PRODUCT.V_CODE" _

Private Sub cmdRunReport_Click()`

Dim strSql As String
Dim strWhereClause As String


strWhereClause = "" 'default initial value

If Not IsNull(Me.TxtStartDate.Value) Then

    strWhereClause = strWhereClause & IIf(strWhereClause <> "", " AND ", "") & "INVOICE.INV_DATE >= #" & Format(Me.TxtStartDate.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# "

End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtEndDate.Value) Then

    strWhereClause = strWhereClause & IIf(strWhereClause <> "", " AND ", "") & "INVOICE.INV_DATE <= #" & Format(Me.txtEndDate.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# "

End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtInvoice.Value) Then

    strWhereClause = strWhereClause & IIf(strWhereClause <> "", " AND ", "") & "INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = '" & Me.txtInvoice.Value & "' "

End If

   strWhereClause = IIf(strWhereClause <> "", " WHERE ", "") & strWhereClause

   strSql = strBaseSql & strWhereClause & " ORDER BY INVOICE.INV_NUMBER, INVOICE.INV_DATE, LINE.LINE_NUMBER"

   CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryInvoiceReport").SQL = strSql

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of strSql prior to using it? 3141 normally means something is wrong with the `SELECT` statement.  Also is INV_NUMBER a string?

Comment: The value of strSql prior to using it is:

Comment: SELECT INVOICE.INV_NUMBER, INVOICE.INV_DATE, CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_LNAME, CUSTOMER.CUS_FNAME, CUSTOMER.CUS_AREACODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_PHONE, LINE.LINE_NUMBER, LINE.P_CODE, PRODUCT.P_DESCRIPT, LINE.LINE_UNITS, LINE.LINE_PRICE, [LINE_PRICE]*[LINE_UNITS] AS LineSubtotal
FROM VENDOR INNER JOIN (CUSTOMER INNER JOIN (PRODUCT INNER JOIN (INVOICE INNER JOIN LINE ON INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = LINE.INV_NUMBER) ON PRODUCT.P_CODE = LINE.P_CODE) ON CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE = INVOICE.CUS_CODE) ON VENDOR.V_CODE = PRODUCT.V_CODE
ORDER BY INVOICE.INV_NUMBER, INVOICE.INV_DATE, LINE.LINE_NUMBER;

Comment: If you just run that select as SQL in a query window, does it run?

Comment: The `strBaseSql` string appears to be missing a space between `LineSubtotal` and `FROM`

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)